# Changing theme from default in the manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-theme

I have an app in the play store: [Just Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pshetye.justnotes)

I recently added themes to the app. 
The problem is, the status bar color and the default background color always default to the theme that is mentioned in the manifest.

All the other themes have the colorPrimaryDark mentioned in them but Android just does not use it for setting the Status bar color at runtime.

How to properly override the theme mentioned in the manifest

eg.
Following are my Styles

> ```
> <style name="AppBaseThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
>   <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_dark</item>
>   <item name="android:textColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
>     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="AppBaseThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_light</item>
>     <item name="android:textColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
>     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
> </style>
> ```

Following is my Manifest

> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppThemeDark" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

The manifest has the app theme set to dark.

In my activity, this how I am setting the theme based on what is saved in the shared pref.

```
switch (mPrefs.getInt("theme", -1)) {
    case 0:
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
        break;
    case 1:
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
        break;
    default:
        //keep the theme from the manifest.
}
```

If the user has selected the light theme, the status bar still remains black as well as the background.

If I change the theme in manifest to AppBaseThemeLight, then the status bar remains grey even for the dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was gonna be only for Lollipop, I fixed it using a custom attribute to set the background based on the theme.

And for the status bar color, I used

> getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor());